# Problems with String in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a written a simple program of average age calculation in Kotlin in the following way:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val age1 = 42.toDouble()
    val age2 = 21.toDouble()

    println("Average = ${(age1 + age2)/2}")
```

The program doesn't work. It expects a '}'.
Even if I change the println statement to the following:

```
println("Average = " + "%.3f".format((age1 + age2)/2))
```

it says that it expects a '}'. 
Don't know what to do. Please help.

Comment: On a side note: `42.toDouble()` -> `42.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the format. You just forgot the `}` that closes your function.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val age1 = 42.toDouble()
    val age2 = 21.toDouble()

    println("Average = ${(age1 + age2)/2}")
} // <- HERE
```